# How to generate XY Scatter Plot

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic spreadsheet that a user adds data to every day.

Once the user runs a report a macro moves data from the input page to a log page. Some of the calculated data from the log page is moved to a different worksheet so it can be used to produce an XY scatter plot.

I have three XY scatter plots from different data sets that are generated via the VBA below.

The VBA produces a chart sheet with two buttons

1. Prints PDF
2. Returns to the previous page and deletes the chart.

Periodically when running the macro Excel will crash.

In addition, randomly the macro produced graph will be scrambled. The Legend will not be correct and the X/Y axis will be incorrect. This happens about 30% of the time at random.
Does it have something do with the chart being deleted each time? Is there a better way to generate these graphs, such as creating the Chart sheet and using the Macro to update the graph? If so, how would the code be different to accomplish this task?

```vb
Sub SalesMigration()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")
        LastRow = getLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables"), 6)
        Set Rng1 = .Range("F1:F" & LastRow & ", G1:G" & LastRow & ", H1:H" & LastRow & ", I1:I" & LastRow)
    End With
    Charts.Add Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Sales and Inventory Data"
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Sales & Inventory"
        .PlotArea.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(2)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(3)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
        
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(900, 115, 100, 50).Select
    With Selection
        .OnAction = "Delete"
        .Characters.Text = "RETURN"
    End With

    ActiveChart.Name = "Sales & Inventory"

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(900, 50, 100, 50).Select
    With Selection
        .OnAction = "PrintGraphs"
        .Characters.Text = "PRINT"
    End With

    ActiveChart.Protect Password:="Sales2022"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Here is the code to return and delete the chart.

```vb
Sub Delete()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Charts.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The getLastRow is a function for finding the last row this platform helped me with previously.

Comment: How would I be able to update an existing chart sheet with the VBA instead of creating a new chart sheet each time?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar than you: I have created an XY-scatter, added an extra line to my data, and updated the source data of my chart to the new data. All this, I recorded it into VBA, and this is what I got:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:B6")
```

As you see, there's no need to remove the graph and recreate it, you can just `SetSourceData` to a new source (in your case, based on `getLastRow()`).